# Implementing Threads via Futures

Tags: java, multithreading, future

I wonder if the following would be a correct implementation

```
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_NSH_THREADS);
    Set<Future<Void>> futureRequest = new HashSet<Future<Void>>();

    for (String host : SomeCollection)) {
        Callable<Void> callable = new FileExtractor(j);
        Future<Void> future = pool.submit(callable);
        futureRequest.add(future);
    }

    for (Future<Void> future : futureRequest) {
        try {
            future.get(); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e);
        }
    }

    pool.shutdown();
```

According to Javadoc, `future.get()` waits for execution to complete for each thread, which (as i understand it) means that for each of the future, we will wait to receive the results separately. Where is the benefit coming from then, or am i not doing it right?

Comment: What benefit are you trying to get?  This seems like it would work but yes, it will simply wait for all the futures to complete before it shuts down the pool...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing it right.

Lets say that `SomeCollection` contains 100 items, and that `FileExtractor` takes 5 seconds to run, and that your `ExecutorService` thread pool contains 100 threads.

If you start things as you have implemented above, it is expected that the code would run for around 5 seconds because `FileExtractor` would likely be I/O bound. (assuming maximum CPU efficiency).

If you didn't use `Future`'s, and everything ran serially, this code would be running for about 500 seconds instead.

The key is that `Future#get()` waits for the result to be populated by the `Thread` started by submitting your `Callable` to the `ExecutorService`, rather than waiting at the `ExecutorService#submit(Callable)` method.

Answer (score 2):

Each future is started as soon as you submit it, by calling `pool.submit`. If your main thread had some other work to do in the meantime (between starting futures, and waiting for them to end), it could easily happen that all your futures are done by the time you got to the second loop, so there would practically be no blocking.

And if the `get` method does block the main thread, while you are waiting for the first `Future` to finish, note that others are still running parallely (at least potentially, given enough processor time).